I want to develop a simple app using kivy to get android gps info (longitude and latitude)
I try to get android gps info (longitude and latitude) using Kivy and plyer but it doesnt work. My code is a main.py file:
from kivy.lang import Builder
from plyer import gps
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.clock import mainthread
from kivy.utils import platform




class GpsTest(App):
    latitude = StringProperty("Unknown")
    longitude = StringProperty("Unknown")
    gps_status = StringProperty('Click Start to get GPS location updates')

    def request_android_permissions(self):
        """
        Since API 23, Android requires permission to be requested at runtime.
        This function requests permission and handles the response via a
        callback.

        The request will produce a popup if permissions have not already been
        been granted, otherwise it will do nothing.
        """
        from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission

        def callback(permissions, results):
            """
            Defines the callback to be fired when runtime permission
            has been granted or denied. This is not strictly required,
            but added for the sake of completeness.
            """
            if all([res for res in results]):
                print("callback. All permissions granted.")
            else:
                print("callback. Some permissions refused.")

        request_permissions([Permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                             Permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION], callback)
        # # To request permissions without a callback, do:
        # request_permissions([Permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
        #                      Permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION])

    def build(self):
        try:
            gps.configure(on_location=self.on_location,
                          on_status=self.on_status)
        except NotImplementedError:
            import traceback
            traceback.print_exc()
            self.gps_status = 'GPS is not implemented for your platform'

        if platform == "android":
            print("gps.py: Android detected. Requesting permissions")
            self.request_android_permissions()

        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    def start(self, minTime, minDistance):
        gps.start(minTime, minDistance)

    def stop(self):
        gps.stop()

    @mainthread
    def on_location(self, **kwargs):
        self.latitude = str(kwargs.get('lat', 'Unknown'))
        self.longitude = str(kwargs.get('lon', 'Unknown'))

    @mainthread
    def on_status(self, stype, status):
        self.gps_status = 'type={}\n{}'.format(stype, status)

    def on_pause(self):
        gps.stop()
        return True

    def on_resume(self):
        gps.start(1000, 0)
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GpsTest().run()


and the buildozer.spce file which is set as follows:
[app]
requirements = python3, kivy, plyer
# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET,ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

[buildozer]

log_level = 2

However it doesnot provide the gps coordinations. The app runs but it doesnt provide gps coordinations such as longitude and latitude.

The code is almost complete to achieve the task to get the GPS coordinates, we can assume this is being used in a device that does have a GPS hardware available, what could be missing is a live listener function that constantly gets the coordinates from the data source (usually plyer module), checking on the code I think there is nothing additionally needed to change, the only thing to change to make it work in Android will be the buildozer.spec details and maybe add more buttons to the GUI:
requirements = kivy==2.3.0,kivymd==0.104.1,python3,pyjnius,plyer,requests,urllib3,chardet,idna,pip,Image,PIL,android

For example adding buttons, text fields, dialog and some additional structure:


To create the dialog you can use Kivymd combined:
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
#...
        self.dialog_x4x=MDDialog(
            title=title,
            text="[color=000000]"+text,
            auto_dismiss=False,
            radius=[self.rr,self.rr,self.rr,self.rr],
            buttons=[
                MDFlatButton(
                    text="Cancelar",
                    text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color,
                    on_release=lambda x:(self.dialog_x4x.dismiss(force=True))),
                MDFillRoundFlatIconButton(
                    markup=True,
                    text="[b]Aceptar",
                    icon="truck-fast",
                    on_release=lambda x:(app.save_...,self.dialog_x4x.dismiss(force=True)))
                
                ],
            )
        self.dialog_x4x.open()

Then compile your app to APK:
python3 -m buildozer -v android debug

